# Set<UITouch> stored property crashing with EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

My class has a stored property declared thus:

```swift
private var touchesBeingTracked:Set<UITouch> = []
```

Later in my code when I access the stored property I get the error

> Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x261)

```swift
internal func containerTouchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?, containerTouchesBeingTrackedCount: Int) {
    var count:Int = self.touchesBeingTracked.count
    // ...
}
```

Searching for data on debugging Swift and `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` (e.g. [here](http://blog.swilliams.me/words/2015/03/31/tracking-down-an-exc-bad-access-with-swift/) and [here](http://www.touch-code-magazine.com/how-to-debug-exc_bad_access/)) it appears most likely that the object I am trying to access (i.e. the stored property on the instance) has been released. This makes no sense to me.

I have tried guarding against this eventuality by adding the lines

```swift
if self.touchesBeingTracked == nil {
    self.touchesBeingTracked = []
}
```

but the compiler complains

> Value of type 'Set' can never be null, comparison isn't allowed

Quite.

How do I diagnose and fix why the line

```swift
var count:Int = self.touchesBeingTracked.count
```

produces an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` crash?

Comment: The code could only crash if `count` is called **before** `touchesBeingTracked` has been initialized.

Comment: But it's initialized on the line that defines it, so how can that happen?

Comment: Is the property be declared on the top level of the class or in a method?

Comment: Top level, it is not nested in anything (I think 'private' can only be used in non-local scope)

Comment: Then it's very strange. Actually the code must not crash, if the property is declared on the top level of the class. Could it be an issue with the private annotation?

Comment: You are not alone there - I have been shouting "the code must not crash" at xcode for the past few hours. It's had no effect. I'll try changing the modifier but instance methods should have access to private stored properties so I doubt that's the problem

Comment: Does changing the declaration and initialization to `private var touchesBeingTracked:Set<UITouch> = Set<UITouch>()` change anything? This is how Apple suggests to initialize `Set` data type.

Comment: Thanks Eugene. That worked. If you want to write that up as an answer I'll mark it as such. A more informative error message or a compiler warning would have been useful.

Comment: That's funny. I suspected the misleading initializer syntax, too. But the code worked in a Playground as well as in a project.